# Turn name of a list into string

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have several lists that I want to write a function and use loop to make multiple heatmaps out of those lists. Then I want to name each heatmap by the name of the list. How can I turn the list name into string?

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [4,5,6], [4,5,6]]
list2 = [[2,2,3], [1,5,1], [4,2,3], [3,3,6]]
data = (list1, list2)
def hm(df):
   sns.set_style("whitegrid")
   ax = sns.heatmap(df, cmap=cmap)
   plt.title('df')
   return fig
for l in data:
   hm(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In a normal case, you cannot retroactively retrieve the name of a variable from it's value. There might be some hacky ways around this, but I would recommend to just use a dictionary to retain the lists name:

```
list1 = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [4,5,6], [4,5,6]]
list2 = [[2,2,3], [1,5,1], [4,2,3], [3,3,6]]
data = {
    "list1": list1,
    "list2": list2,
}

def hm(name, df):
   sns.set_style("whitegrid")
   ax = sns.heatmap(df, cmap=cmap)
   plt.title('df')
   # Do something with the name variable
   return fig
   
for name, l in data.items():
    hm(name, l)
```